# Issue comparing parsed serial data

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I am having an issue getting my function to carry on past the if(Status == "True") statement but i am not sure why. when i print the lines they seem to match. I also included a sample of the serial output.

b'RCSSTATUS\r\n' b' False\r\n' b'RCSSTATUS\r\n' b' False\r\n' b'RCSSTATUS\r\n' b' False\r\n'

com = command = DATASET = 'RCSSTATUS ' + result + '\n' = True

```
void parseCommand(String com){

String Action;
String Status;
Action = com.substring(0, com.indexOf(" "));
Status = com.substring(9, com.indexOf("e") + 1);
    Serial.println(Action);
if(Action == "RCSSTATUS")
{Serial.println(Status);
    if(Status == "True"){
        digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
}
        if(Status == "False"){
                            digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(5, LOW);
}}}
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to include the actual value of `com`?

Comment: The code is updated with COM which is actually being parsed from a serial input which is RCSSTATUS True

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My output string had a space on the beginning of the line. changed `if(Status == "True")` to `if(Status == " True")`